# Should I destroy all body joints before destroying body in Box2D?

Tags: box2d

Does Box2D destroy all body joints automatically or should I manually do this? Can destroying body without destroying joint cause crash or memory leak?

Comment: Huh, it's late reply, but @m.antkowicz is right. If you don't destroy joints manually, your program will likely crash and burn. You should destroy them manually. Please read the manual: http://box2d.org/manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

here is the Box2d manual - read **8.3** section

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974

to sum up - it is good practise to destroy joints manually - they should be destroyed when corresponding bodies are destroyed (and that's why it will not cause the crash/leak rather) but it is not guaranteed.